# How do I get the winnings for each cycle to accumulate?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

```
int rounds = 0;
        do
        {
            int winnings = lottery.showWinnings(setA);
            rounds = rounds + 1; 
        }
        while (rounds != weeks);
```

`lottery.showWinnings(setA)` returns an integer value. I want the `winnings` value in the first cycle of the loop to be taken and added to the `winnings` value in the second cycle of the loop and so on until the cycle has been repeated the number of times that the integer `weeks` holds. Is there anyway to do that? I've tried a `for` loop but that has the same issue

Comment: The same way you keep a cumulative total of the number of rounds.

Comment: probably you need to declare `winnings` outside of the loop and the results of the method calls `showWinnings(setA)` to it?

Comment: or if you had in mind to create a combination of winning numbers, then  winnings has to be an array

Comment: @DaveNewton i'm just adding 1 to the number of rounds each time. I want to add the value ```winnings``` to the next ```winnings``` value each time

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I just want the value ```winnings``` to be added to the next ```winnings``` value until the loop finishes

Comment: So have a reference initialized outside the loop and add the value to it--just like you add one to "rounds". It's the exact same process, except instead of adding one to "rounds" you're adding the retrieved "winnings" value to a total winnings accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :-

```
int rounds = 0;
int winnings = 0;
        do
        {
            winnings += lottery.showWinnings(setA);
            rounds ++; 
        }
        while (rounds != weeks);
```

Comment: Do mark as the answer if you found it helpful!